# Wait for a method with axios to complete before proceeding

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, axios

I am Studying vue.js and stuck with the concept of promise. I want one of my variable to be initialized with the data from API call and I want to make sure that the `axios` call will be generic:

```
{
  data: {
    list: [],
  },
  methods: {
    ShowList: function () {
      return this.Axios_GET('/api/Api_Store').then(items => {
        this.list = items;
      });
    },

    Axios_GET: function (apiurl) {
      // I want to keep this as a reusable method and don't want  to bind variable inside this method
      this.StartProgress();
      axios({ method: 'get', url: apiurl }).then((response) => {
        this.StopProgress();
        return Response.data;

      }).catch((error) => {
        this.StopProgress();
      }).then(function () {

      });
    },
  }
};
```

when I try `ShowList`, I am getting below error:

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"
```

I want to set the ShowList function to get data from API like below  (conceptually)

```
this.list = this.Axios_GET('/api/Api_Store')
```

NB: `StartProgress` and `StopProgress` functions are already defined and working fine.

Comment: You just forgot to `return` anything from your function, so it returns `undefined`

Comment: can you  just mention which function or post the correct snippet

Comment: in this `Axios_GET: function (apiurl) {` you have to return like `return axios({ method: 'get', url: apiurl }).then((response) => {`.

Comment: @Ravikumar But still the   this.list = items;  is undefined but i can see data when debugging the axios response in Axios_GET

Comment: @SreenathGanga, you don't need second then in `Axios_GET`, just remove that it'll work.

Comment: @Ravikumar  working fine.. if you want you can add the changes as answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can use promise chaining.

```js
{
  data: {
    list: [],
  },
  methods: {
    ShowList: function() {
      return this.Axios_GET('/api/Api_Store').then(items => {
        this.list = items || [];
      });
    },

    Axios_GET: function(apiurl) {
      this.StartProgress();
      return axios({
          method: 'get',
          url: apiurl
        })
        .then(response => response.data)
        .catch((error) => {
          // handle error if needed;
        }).finally(() => {
          this.StopProgress();
        });
    },
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  data: {
    list: [],
  },
  methods: {
    ShowList: function () {
      return this.Axios_GET('/api/Api_Store').then(items => {
        this.list = items;
      });
    },

    Axios_GET: function (apiurl) {
      // I want to keep this as a reusable method and don't want  to bind variable inside this method
      this.StartProgress();
      axios({ method: 'get', url: apiurl }).then((response) => {
        this.StopProgress();
        return response.data; // <--- I think here needs to be response.data not Response.data, think this will help

      }).catch((error) => {
        this.StopProgress();
      }).then(function () {

      });
    },
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the empty `then()` at the end of the `axios` promise chain and also propagate the error in catch block using `Promise.reject()`. Finally, return the axis promise chain from the function.

If you do not propagate the error then, the promise would become resolved state and your `ShowList` function would break.

Here is the modified code:

```
{
  data() {
    return {
      list: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ShowList: function () {
      return this.Axios_GET('/api/Api_Store').then(items => {
        this.list = items;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // Handle error here (Show warning/error)
        this.list = [];
      });
    },

    Axios_GET: function (apiurl) {
      
      this.StartProgress();
      
      // RETURN is important.
      return axios({ method: 'get', url: apiurl }).then((response) => {
        this.StopProgress();
        
        return response.data;
      }).catch((error) => {
        this.StopProgress();

        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
    },
  }
};
```